# C++ Text based Game ( Unknown Error )

Tags: c++, runtime-error

Trying to create a simple text based game and everything has gone OK so fr but When the user inputs N into userinput2 it not only  prints the text but also take's me back to the menu I have no idea why could anyone explain this to me?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main (){
    bool done = false;
        while (!done) {
        char userinput;
        string name;
        char yes = 'Y';
        char no = 'N';
        char userinput2;


    cout << "#############################################" << endl;
    cout << "#=======|| ##  The Age OF Zorak ## ||=======#" << endl;
    cout << "#############################################" << endl;
    cout << "   #######################################   " << endl;
    cout << "     #################################       " << endl; 
    cout << "       #############################         " << endl;
    cout << "         #########################           " << endl;
    cout << "           ======================            " << endl;
    cout << "             ==================              " << endl;
    cout << "               ==============                " << endl;
    cout << "                 {}{}{}{}{}                  " << endl; 
    cout << "                  ........                   " << endl;
    cout << "                   ||||||                    " << endl;
    cout << "                    ||||                     " << endl;
    cout << "                     ||                      " << endl;
    cout << "                     ()                      " << endl;
    cout << "                                             " << endl;


    cout << "\n";
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "\n";

    cout << "---------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "               ----Start----                 " << endl;
    cout << "---------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "               ---- Y/N ----                 " << endl;
    cout << "---------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << ">>: ";          
    cin  >> userinput;
    if (userinput == yes){
        cout <<"Welcome,stranger what is your name?" << endl;
        cout <<">>: ";
        cin  >> name;
        cout << "I see a long road for you " <<name <<"," << endl;
        cout << "Perhaps you would like some water?" << endl;
        cout << ">>Take the water from the old man?<<" << endl;
        cout << "(Y/N)>>: ";
        cin  >> userinput2;

            if (userinput2 == 'N'){
            cout << "You refuse the water but thank the man for the offer." << endl;
            cout << "leaving the Inn, you feel much rested but your coin purse" <<endl;
            cout << "feels light...It's time to get some gold!!!!" << endl;     
            }

                if (userinput2 == yes){
                cout << "You sip the water and thank the kind old man." << endl;
                cout << "Moments after drinking the water,the room begins to spin"<< endl;
                cout << "the old man's laughter is the last thing you hear...." << endl;
                cout << "<<< You are DEAD >>>" << endl;
                cout << "<<< Try again? >>>" << endl;
                cout << "(Y/N)" << endl;

                char answer;
                cin >> answer;
                tolower(answer);
                if (answer == no) done = true;
         }
      }        

   }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the user enters 'N', then the condition of your while loop still remains true - so it starts over.

Comment: But i thought that was within it's own block

Comment: I would suggest that you format the code - nested if statements are hard to look at when they're not properly aligned. Also, your teacher or who ever else is working on this will thank you for that - trust me ;)

Comment: @ Thanks Mike :) will make it neater !!!!

Comment: Where are the braces for this if statement: if (userinput2 == 'N')?

Comment: Added the missing brace for that statement and made sure all braces are correct but when I press N It still changes the condition of my Loop ><

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/PIhAQww.png

Comment: Your braces and indentation here are very broken. Try placing braces and indenting the code after every conditional for the block of code that conditional applies to. Once you get this code "working" you could probably get a lot of good advice on how to improve things with your overall coding by posting it over on http://codereview.stackexchange.com . Just make sure it's in working order though first because broken code asking for debugging is going to be off topic for there.

Comment: Update the code in your post with what you have now (formatted too!)

Comment: @shuttle87 Yeah I am very new to coding so not even sure how the indentation should be !!! There is a lot of if statements going on within if statements is there a simpler way of doing this ?

Comment: @marmaa, if you can get this code into a working state (see my answer for a suggestion on that) then I would be more than happy to provide those suggestions if you were to make a post over on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . I suggest that site because this type of question is a lot more on-topic over there.

Comment: @shuttle87 Only if he gets it working. Currently there is a major bug, making it off-topic. Fix the bug here, then post it on CR.

Comment: @Mast, that's why I explicitly added the disclaimer to the comments that the code has to first be fixed and be in working order before it can be posted over there.

Comment: @shuttle87 Things tend to be read only half here, that's why I posted it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the beginning of all this you have a while loop

```
bool done = false;
while (!done) {
    //everything in here keeps looping until
    //the condition doesn't hold at the beginning of this loop
}
```

This will keep looping until the condition `!done` evaluates to false or in other words until `done` is set to true. Within this loop you print out the starting screen. So until you set done to true this start screen will keep getting printed out.

So far so good.

Now the program behaves just as expected because:

```
    cout << "(Y/N)>>: ";
    cin  >> userinput2;

        if (userinput2 == 'N'){
             //code for the no option
             //note that done is never changed in here (important!)
        }

            if (userinput2 == yes){
            //code for yes option
            char answer;
            cin >> answer;
            tolower(answer);
            if (answer == no) done = true; //done IS handled but only in the "yes" branch from above
     }
```

Because you never change the value of `done` when the user enters `'N'` the loop continues on looping. And as explained earlier the start screen is printed every time the loop runs.

To fix you need to set the value of `done` whenever the game is finished. By making the braces and indentation clearer it is much easier to visually spot where these changes occur, this is the main reason why me and others have suggested that you improve the formatting of your code.

There's a lot of different things that could be improved about this code, however that would be more on topic on the [code review site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this to me !!!! I will try and improve on my indentation as you suggest

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at your code I'd check each { against the matching } to make sure the program flows as you'd expect. Something doesn't look right with these to me. I can only see 4 close braces and these are all at the end of you code.

Once you have formatted the code better it's a little easier to see that you are checking the user input to go again with  `tolower(answer)` against a variable with the value `'N'`. I think the `tolower(answer)` would never equal an upper case char. - having looked back at your code I don't think this actually does anything as the `tolower()` function is called on it's own.

Comment: checked the braces and made them more ordered... but the error is still occurring in regards to changing the while loop condition outside of the block of code that should be doing that any ideas?

Comment: As I understand your code you intend the 'if' statements to perform some conditional operation but without the open '{' and close '}' braces structured correctly, all the code runs. You chose in your example to refuse the water but if you accept I'd guess you'd see the same text 'You refuse the water but thank...' plus the expected text. Does that give you some idea where to look?

Comment: This is what the output is at the moment

Comment: The improved code with braces for each if statement appears to correct my last comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

here man, start with this:

```
    bool done = false;
    while (!done) {
        char userinput;
        string name;
        char yes = 'Y';
        char no = 'N';
        char userinput2;


        cout << "#############################################" << endl;
        cout << "#=======|| ##  The Age OF Zorak ## ||=======#" << endl;
        cout << "#############################################" << endl;
        cout << "   #######################################   " << endl;
        cout << "     #################################       " << endl; 
        cout << "       #############################         " << endl;
        cout << "         #########################           " << endl;
        cout << "           ======================            " << endl;
        cout << "             ==================              " << endl;
        cout << "               ==============                " << endl;
        cout << "                 {}{}{}{}{}                  " << endl; 
        cout << "                  ........                   " << endl;
        cout << "                   ||||||                    " << endl;
        cout << "                    ||||                     " << endl;
        cout << "                     ||                      " << endl;
        cout << "                     ()                      " << endl;
        cout << "                                             " << endl;


        cout << "\n";
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "\n";
        cout << "\n";

        cout << "---------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "               ----Start----                 " << endl;
        cout << "---------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "               ---- Y/N ----                 " << endl;
        cout << "---------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << ">>: ";          
        cin  >> userinput;
        if (userinput == 'Y'){
            cout <<"Welcome,stranger what is your name?" << endl;
            cout <<">>: ";
            cin  >> name;
            cout << "I see a long road for you " <<name <<"," << endl;
            cout << "Perhaps you would like some water?" << endl;
            cout << ">>Take the water from the old man?<<" << endl;
            cout << "(Y/N)>>: ";
            cin  >> userinput2;

            if (userinput2 == 'N'){
                cout << "You refuse the water but thank the man for the offer." << endl;
                cout << "leaving the Inn, you feel much rested but your coin purse" <<endl;
                cout << "feels light...It's time to get some gold!!!!" << endl;     
            }

            if (userinput2 == 'Y'){
                cout << "You sip the water and thank the kind old man." << endl;
                cout << "Moments after drinking the water,the room begins to spin"<< endl;
                cout << "the old man's laughter is the last thing you hear...." << endl;
                cout << "<<< You are DEAD >>>" << endl;
                cout << "<<< Try again? >>>" << endl;
                cout << "(Y/N)" << endl;

                char answer;
                cin >> answer;
                tolower(answer);
                if (answer == 'n') done = true;
            }
        }        

    }
```

Comment: Right, I wasn't fixing the bug for you - I think it's important that you understand why it isn't working. I just needed the formatting to not make my head hurt.

Comment: When you type 'N' into userinput2 - the variable done is still set to false. So, the loop then starts from the top again. This essentially starts your game over.

Comment: Starting to think I would be better off just using the dreaded GOTO

Comment: What do you want to happen after the user types 'N' into userinput2?

Comment: Would like the game to carry on running I think i may have over complicated it in terms of my skill level

Comment: Then you have to write more of your game! You've reached the end of your game after you decide to tell the old man to take his water and shove it! Do you understand how while loops work? [note: I am not making a dig at you: I know that when people just start coding it is not easy]. But, now I feel too committed to helping. Lol

Comment: Not 100 percent on while loops No ( any help is welcome I am trying to teach myself from having zero experience and it is overwhelming at times)

Comment: I understand, I did the same thing awhile ago - and now I do it for work.  Do you understand why when you enter Y into userinput2 you get the desired result?

Comment: yes i understand that much I am sort of improving i guess

Comment: Looks like you've found your way - happy coding!